# Linux Kernel compile: File format not recognized

Tags: 12.04, kernel, compiling

I compile the latest kernel version 4.15.15. My current kernel is 3.13 on Ubuntu 12.04, gcc version is 7.3.0.  When it executes the command `make`, it has many errors, such as

```
objdump: mm/.tmp_oom_kill.o: File format not recognized
```

How to fix the problems?

[image: Errors screenshot]

Comment: What is your platform exactly (32 or 64 bits?)? What exact commands did you use to compile? Please put the error messages as text not with a picture.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is past its end-of-life, so is off-topic here. You need to switch to a supported release.

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: ubuntu is 32bits. I only execute the command 'make', resulting in errors.@ Patrick Mevzek

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this tmp file is left over from a failed build. I suggest removing the object file and re-trying the build.

You can use the file command to find out more about the file, e.g.:

```
file mm/.tmp_oom_kill.o
```

maybe that will explain why you are getting that error.